# Google Firebase Cloud Functions generates error when using Firestore and implemented per the docs

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

With the following code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
admin.initializeApp()

exports.onTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  res.json({ msg: 'done' })
})
```

which comes exactly from the [example docs](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore/functions/index.js), ... running `firebase emulators:start` from cli generates the following error:

```
 ⚠  TypeError: instance.registerVersion is not a function
    at registerDatabase (/Users/<path>/functions/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15188:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/<path>/functions/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:15200:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at FirebaseNamespace.get [as database] (/Users/tremendus/Development/kulanu/playground/kulanu-cloud/functions/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:282:38)
⚠  We were unable to load your functions code. (see above)
```

Several other examples on SO and other sites call `#initializeApp` with `initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)` ... but this also throws the same error.

I'm using node 8 functions and node 8 locally and basic pacakage.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

UPDATE: although the command `firebase emulators:start` throws the above error, the functions work in shell:

```
MacPro:functions: firebase functions:shell
✔  functions: Emulator started at http://localhost:5000
>  function: apiOnSave
i  functions: Loaded functions: apiOnSave
firebase > apiOnSave()
Sent request to function.
firebase > >  function: apiOnSave

RESPONSE RECEIVED FROM FUNCTION: 200, {
  "msg": "done"
}
```

Doesn't anyone have suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: PS - this is the only function in my function library

Comment: If you have updates or modification to your question, you can simply edit the question instead of adding a comment.

Comment: If have clear reproduction steps that suggest there might be a bug in the Firebase CLI, please post an issue on the Firebase CLI GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson - I can't reproduce it in a freshly initialized project ... that does work. But if I copy the firebase config files and functions folder from the fresh initialized folder to the project folder, I still get the error. the same also occurs if I re-init the project folder. Are there any other config files or a cache that might be affecting why it works in a fresh folder, but not in a freshly initialized existing folder?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a bug in `firebase@7.6.1`. Going back to `firebase@7.6.0` fixes it for me.

## Direct Dependecy

Since for me, `firebase` is a direct dependency, this does the trick:

`npm i -S firebase@7.6.0 --force`

## Indirect dependency

However in your case, it is an indirect dependency -- Try to find out which version your installation uses with:

`npm list firebase`

Try going back to a version of `firebase-admin` and `firebase-functions` that uses an earlier version of `firebase`.